# Solving a bivariate recursion $f(k, n) = n^m f(k-n, m)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, functional-equations, recursion

I have encountered an unknown object that seems to obey the following recursion, for any integers $k \geq n, m \geq 1$,

$$
f(k, n) = n^m f(k-n, m)
$$

I think that $f(k, n) = 0$ is a solution to this (or is it?), but I am wondering if there are any other non-trivial solutions to this recursion, given the value $f(k, 1)$. (Or if it is possible to prove this has no non-trivial solution).

Thanks.

Comment: For $m= 0$, $n > 0$ your equation says $f(k,n) = f(k-n,0)$, which your boundary condition says is $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for the quick answer. I realized that what I have in mind is not exactly what I originally wrote. I have edited my boundary condition and my domain of interest accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so now with $m=1$, $f(k,n) = n f(k-n,1)$.  In particular for $n=1$, $f(k,1) = f(k-1,1)$, i.e. $f(\cdot,1)$ is constant.  If $c = f(1,1)$, $f(k,n) = n c$, and your equation then says $ n c = n^m m c$.  Taking e.g. $m=2$ and $n > 0$, we see that the only possibility is $c=0$.